# Angular 2 <template> and pipes

Tags: angular, pipe, ngfor

What's the syntax to use a pipe (async for example) in this construction:

```
<template let-item [ngForOf]="items">
   ...
</template>
```

P.S. I know how to use a pipe with `*ngFor` but I need `<template>`

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing special

```
<template let-item [ngForOf]="items | somePipe">
```

Comment: Ok. So, it needs to be inside ngForOf quotations. Thanks!